# element.style disabled in one server

Tags: java, html, jquery, css

I have 2 servers, running a `Java web application`, identical war file and CSS deployed on both machines. On testing, the layout is broken in one server since the attribute `style="display: none;"`  for a div element is missing. On the other server, it works as expected.

On loading the webpage through Edge and debugging, I see this under developer tools on hitting the server that works correctly.

```
element.style {
  display: none;
}
```

On the second server, the `element.style` is disabled and not editable through developer tools.

What is causing this behavior? Same WAR, CSS and browser used for testing.
The server that's broke has load balancer. Will it make any difference?

I do have `<!DOCTYPE html>` in my html.

Comment: What's a war file?

Comment: @j08691 It's like a jar file :). It's a Java thing... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)

Comment: @j08691- thats the application deployment file. Its  a web application

Comment: then the question might should be labled with `Java`?

Comment: How does the `style="display:none"` get on the element? Did someone type it in there, or is there some piece of code somewhere that adds it?

Comment: There are some confusing items in this question: _"On debugging in Edge, I see this on the server that works correctly."_ -- how are you debugging the server in the browser?  Also, this `element.style { display: none; }`-- do you mean `element.class`?

Comment: @tacoshy- the problem is not Java related, it has to be the browser/css/javascript related I think.

Comment: Note: please don't use code formatting for emphasis. Code formatting should be used for, well, code. The phrase "Java web application" is not code, nor is "WAR, CSS and browser". I edited the latter earlier; I'll leave the rest.

Comment: @AlexanderNied - updated my post, please review

Comment: @AlexanderNied I believe `element.style` refers to the entry seen in the Styles sub-tab of the Elements tab of the Developer Tools in Edge, that shows inline styles.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - you are correct about `element.style`

Comment: @AlexanderNied- `element.style` is injected somehow. It's not in the code. We use JQuery.hide() function. Maybe its adding the styling as well behind the scene? If that's the case, its all part of the WAR file. It should be available in both servers.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was browser cache causing the problem. Clearing it fixed it.